# Exactly what is unsafe about this static_cast?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, static-cast

I have written a small example of an unsafe `static_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual int getA(){ return 1; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual int getA() { return 2; }
    int getB() { return 3; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    B* b1 = static_cast<B*>(&a);

    std::cout << "b.getA(): " << b.getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.getB(): " << b.getB() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1->getA(): " << b1->getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1->getB(): " << b1->getB() << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
b.getA(): 2
b.getB(): 3
b1->getA(): 1
b1->getB(): 3
```

I consider it unsafe because I never run the `B` constructor when creating `b1`, though accessing it as a `B` object. Obviously the difference in output shows that `b1` does not point to a `B` object but an `A` object, as expected.

What other aspects of this is unsafe. Does it involve undefined behavior to even perform the `static_cast` like this? Otherwise, is it perhaps undefined behavior to access the `getA` or `getB` methods?

Anything else? (i don't care about the missing virtual destructor which i don't care about in this example)

Code available on cpp.sh: http://cpp.sh/7sxtz

Comment: I'd like to find out how you got this to run!

Comment: http://cpp.sh/7sxtz

Comment: Let me rephrase that: I'd like to know how the OP got it to run *correctly*. I recognize the UB. :-)

Comment: @JonHarper UB means anything can happen (including expected results or otherwise)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: @JonHarper The code doesn't access any non-static member data, so it's likely that it'll run "correctly".

Comment: Please see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/79249/

Comment: please don't, the info in that link is wrong (like most of the articles on that site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static_cast<B *>(&a)` causes undefined behaviour.

C++14 [expr.static.cast]/11:

> [...]  If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the value of `*b1` after carrying out that `static_cast` is undefined behaviour:

> `[basic.lval]/10 (N3337):`
>   If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined
>
> — the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-
>   static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union),
>
> — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a char or unsigned char type.